# Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-5"

Tags: maven

While doing maven build I am receiving following error.
Does anybody know how to resolve it?

Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "Thread-1" Exception in thread "Thread-7" Exception in thread "Thread-3" Exception in thread "Thread-4" Exception in thread "Thread-2" Exception in thread "Thread-5" Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
    Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-1"
    Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-7"
    Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-3"
    Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-4"
    Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-2"
    Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-5"

```
 Results :

    Tests run: 100, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 01:14 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-11T00:12:46+01:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 87M/704M
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project coba.zaa.engine.workflow: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
    [ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C "C:\xxxxx\Tools\Release2\JDK\jdk_1.7.0.80_x64\jre\bin\java -jar C:\vvv\ZAA\nnnn\mmmmmm\target\surefire\surefirebooter1494547892126715647.jar C:\vvv\ZAA\nnnn\mmmmmm\\target\surefire\surefire2662483945733244110tmp C:\vvv\ZAA\nnnn\mmmmmm\target\surefire\surefire_05005140060060096785tmp"
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Comment: finally its working with this solution:<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
     <configuration>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
      <fork>true</fork>
      <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=500M</argLine>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the memory settings in the JVM that the surefire plugin forks.  These aren't inherited from the main MAVEN_OPTS, so need to be set directly in the pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx2g</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I tried with this   <configuration>
                              <argLine>-Xms8g -Xmx8g -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=4096m</argLine>
       <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
       <archive>
        <manifest>
         <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
         <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
         <build-id>${build-id}</build-id>
        </manifestEntries>
       </archive>
      </configuration>

Comment: but still not working

Comment: That <configuration> sample with <attachClasses> etc sounds like it is from the maven-war-plugin?  If so, you'll need two separate <plugin> sections, one for maven-war-plugin, and one for maven-surefire-plugin.

Comment: still not working <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <fork>true</fork>
       <argLine>-Xmx4G -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</argLine>
      </configuration>
     </plugin>